# Trouble with [Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data] in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I still have this trouble after a few attempts to resolve it.

First:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = method, y = age)) + 
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot()
```

R said:

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I try with this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = na.omit(method), y = na.omit(age))) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot()
```

and R said:

> Error:  Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (6253): x, y

Please help me.

Comment: Can you try `ggplot(na.omit(dat), aes(x = method, y = age)) + 
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot()` ?

Comment: I am sorry. Your code did not work. With it, R did not notify any problems, but I could not see anything in plot area. Could you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: I tried this code and it worked
    ggplot(subset(dat, !is.na(age) & !is.na(method)), aes(x = method, y = age)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot()

Comment: great...you can add it as an answer.

Comment: I tried to post but it failed. Thank you very much.